# Can CSS psuedo content pull the element's text?

Tags: css

```
<p class="test">Lorem Ipsum Dolor.</p>
```

Can a CSS psuedo-element's (:before/:after) content property pull from the DOM element's plain text?

```
.test:after{ content: html; }
```

With the result of...

```
 Lorem Ipsum Dolor.Lorem Ipsum Dolor.
```

Looking for a non-JavaScript solution (if one is possible).

Thanks :)

Comment: No, but you could put the content in a `data-*` attribute and then use the `attr()` function... (e.g., `.test:after { content: attr(data-content); }`. It would still be rendered as a string though (not HTML). Example -> https://jsfiddle.net/saqwvm9b/

Comment: @JoshCrozier you should add that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's currently not possible to retrieve the element's text and display it using the `content` property without using JavaScript. However, as I pointed out in the comments, you can use the [CSS `attr()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) in order to retrieve the element's attribute value and display it.

For instance, you could add a custom `data-content` attribute to the element:

```css
[data-content]:after {
  content: attr(data-content);
}
```

```html
<p data-content="Lorem Ipsum Dolor."></p>
```

If you want to display the same string twice (as your question implies), you could simply use multiple `attr()` functions:

```css
[data-content]:after {
  content: attr(data-content) ' ' attr(data-content);
}
```

```html
<p data-content="Lorem Ipsum Dolor."></p>
```

If you use JavaScript, you could simply iterate over the elements and add a custom `data-content` attribute to the element(s) based on the `textContent` property of the element:

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-content]'), function (element) {
  element.dataset.content = element.textContent;
});
```

```css
[data-content]:after {
  content: ' ' attr(data-content);
}
```

```html
<p data-content>Lorem Ipsum Dolor.</p>

<p data-content>Some other string.</p>
```

It's also worth mentioning that the `content` property's value is still rendered as a string (and not HTML).